# overlapping rows in table in responsive view

Tags: css, html-table, media-queries, responsive

I'm having a trouble fixing the table on [this link](https://www.colonialacres.com/product-p/wbs-f9-dl-l.htm)  . It has two rows, but when I turn it to mobile/tablet views, the second row overlaps over the first row.

It looks like this on the attachment:

[image]

Please help. I'm not really good in CSS.

Comment: Can you please provide your code example, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of these lines:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 994px)
table.colors_pricebox tbody tr:last-child td:nth-child(2) table:first-child tbody tr:first-child
{ 
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

`Absolute` positionings do overlap each other if they have the same margins.

If you remove the attribute or replace it by `position: relative` the  `<tr>` - tags don't overlap anymore, but you have to find a way to display your `<tr>` - tags containing the price tag and such.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the fix i recommend for quick turn around for the moment. Add this css in your media queries**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 994px) {
  td.productDetailDiscountWrapper table tr td {
    padding-top: 50px !important;
  }
  .product_productprice {
    margin-top: 40px !important;
  }
}
```